# Why is my MySQL function returning NULL?

Tags: mysql, function

**Function:**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ToYear` $$
CREATE FUNCTION .`ToYear` (input varchar(47)) RETURNS year
BEGIN
  RETURN year(str_to_date(@input,_utf8'%m/%d/%Y'));
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Function call**

```
SELECT ToYear('8/12/2013')
```

Why is it my function is returning NULL when put into a SELECT statement it returns the year?

```
SELECT year(str_to_date('8/12/2013',_utf8'%m/%d/%Y'));
```

Returns: `2013`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ToYear` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `ToYear` (input char(10)) RETURNS year
BEGIN
  RETURN year(str_to_date(input,_utf8'%m/%d/%Y'));
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```